# Is it possible to use a wasm (web assembly )file in flutter android app using flutter web view?

Tags: flutter, webassembly, flutterwebviewplugin

I found the solution. I am writing here for any further need .

this is my final js function .

I have converted my C++ code to a sum.wasm file .

```
function sum(x, y) {   
  const request = new XMLHttpRequest();    
  request.open('GET', 'sum.wasm');      
  request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';      
  request.onload = () => {   
    const wasmBytes = request.response;   
    const imports = {
      env: {
        __stack_pointer: new WebAssembly.Global({ value: 'i32', mutable: true }, 1024),   
               __memory_base: 0,   
               memory: new WebAssembly.Memory({ initial: 128 ,maximum : 1024}),   
               __table_base: 0,   
               __indirect_function_table: new WebAssembly.Table({ initial: 0, element: 'anyfunc' }),}   
   
    };   
    WebAssembly.instantiate(wasmBytes, imports).then(result => {
       
        const  sum = result.instance.exports.add;//"add" function in the C++ code 
        const result2 = sum(x,y);
        console.log(result2);
        myJavaScriptChannel.postMessage( result2);
      }).catch(console.error);   };   
  request.send();   
}
```

Comment: hi @behzad-ahmad-ali-nejad , Yes, it is possible.
But it is better to edit your question and put the your wasm file so that it can be used as a reproduction code for the respondents.

Comment: hi @EsmaeilAhmadipour I have provided my code . it seems that wasm file is loaded but there is a "memory access out of bounds" error that I I could not solve it .

Comment: I found the issue .I edited my code . It worked for me .

Comment: you said in flutter android using flutter web view, but you've provided a solution in JS file... could you please clarify it?

Comment: Right. Now you can call the js function in flutter app using flutter web view